# Como converter um objeto em kotlin do tipo Any! para algum outro que seja possível acessar os campos?

Tags: android, kotlin

Bom dia,

Estou com um problema um pouco chato de ser resolvido em um projeto. Estou tentando fazer um aplicativo que vai se comunicar com o ERP odoo, porém, este ERP usa o protocolo xml-rpc para as suas requisições.

Para fazer as requisições estou usando a lib axml-rpc para android. É uma biblioteca feita em java, mas parece está funcionando. Quando eu chamo uma função remota do odoo, a lib me retorna um objeto Any! com as respostas, porém, eu não consigo acessar as informações.

É possível acessar esse HashMap dentro da variável nome ou essa cor azul indica algum problema? Desde já agradeço!

Ps: Eu já tentei diversos casts, mas nenhum deu certo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem como postar um exemplo de payload recebido na comunicação?

Comment: E como eu verificaria o payload? Teria que usar o postman?

Comment: Bem, isso só você pode responder. Mas sim, geralmente usando o Postman, Fiddler ou SOAPUI você consegue

Comment: Vou ver o que eu consigo fazer, infelizmente essa api não tem muita documentação. Mas no estado atual, não é possível acessar o conteúdo das variáveis mesmo o debugger dizendo que elas contem a data?

Inicialmente eu fiz um teste com o python e foi bem tranquila a comunicação.

Comment: Quando tu faz o cast ele apresenta algum erro? Nessa resposta a pessoa fez um cast de Any pra List: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45107473/how-to-cast-any-to-a-list-in-kotlin

Comment: Se eu tento um cast com o as, recebo a seguinte exceção: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.util.List

Quando eu uso o as?, retorna null.

Answer (score 1):

Eu recomendaria você a entender o que a biblioteca faz em Java ([lendo a documentação](https://github.com/gturri/aXMLRPC)), quais são os tipos com que ela trabalha, pra depois transpor pra Kotlin.

De acordo com a documentação, você está recebendo um `array` (que é representado na biblioteca como um `Object[]` em Java). Dentro desse `array`, baseado no print, existe um `struct` (representado na biblioteca por um `Map<String,Object>`)

Traduzindo essa estrutura inicial, você teria em Kotlin:

- Um `Array<Any>` - Equivalente ao `Object[]`
- Dentro do array, um `Map<String, Any>`

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação! Já tinha dado uma olhada na documentação, mas mesmo assim continua não dando certo acessar o Map.

Acabei descobrindo que o Odoo também suporta o protocolo json-rpc, então acabei desistindo de usar essa lib.